# Change colour of colorbar in Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, colorbar

I have a code that gives me a scatter plot of predicted vs actual values as a function of concentration. The data is pulled from an excel csv spreadsheet.

This is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import loadtxt


dataset = loadtxt("ColorPlot.csv", delimiter=',')
x = dataset[:,0]
y = dataset[:,1]
z = dataset[:,2]

scaled_z = (z - z.min()) / z.ptp()

colors = plt.cm.viridis(scaled_z)
sc=plt.scatter(x, y, c=colors)
plt.clim(0, 100)
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("Actual")
plt.ylabel("Predicted")

plt.show()
```

And with this I get a nice graph:
[image]

However if I change the color to something like

```
colors = plt.cm.plasma(scaled_z)
```

I get the graph below but the colorbar remains unchanged.

[image]

I've tried lots of different things like cmap or edgecolors but I don't know how to change it. And I want to keep the code as simple as it currently is because I want to readily change the third variable of z based on my excel spreadsheet data.

Is there also a way for the scale of the colorbar to pick up what the scale is from the excel spreadsheet without me manually specifying 0-100?

Comment: The standard way is to call it as `plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap='plasma')`. And leaving out `plt.clim()`. In that standard way, the colorbar will get the 'plasma' colors, and will have indications of the lowest and highest z values.  If, instead, you want the colorbar to go between 0 and 100, you could do `scaled_z = 100*(z - z.min()) / z.ptp()` and `plt.scatter(x, y, c=scaled_z, cmap='plasma')`. In any case, it is best to leave out `plt.clim()`

Comment: Omg thats perfect. Literally solved it straight away. Thanks so much. I removed the scaled z term, put cmap in the scatter term and removed plt.clim(). Perfect thanks @JohanC

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the right color bar, use the following code:

```
colormap = plt.cm.get_cmap('plasma') # 'plasma' or 'viridis'
colors = colormap(scaled_z)
sc = plt.scatter(x, y, c=colors)
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=colormap)
sm.set_clim(vmin=0, vmax=100)
plt.colorbar(sm)
plt.xlabel("Actual")
plt.ylabel("Predicted")
plt.show()
```

For my random generated data I got the following plot:

[image]

Now replace `'plasma'` with `'viridis'` and check the other variant.

Answer (score 1):

You should not scale your data, unless you want the colorbar to be incorrect.   Once you have the PathCollection from the scatter call, you can call `set_cmap` and `set_clim` on that and the colorbar should track.  (you could also explicitly associate the colorbar with the PathCollection to avoid ambiguity)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x = np.random.randn(100)
y = np.random.randn(100)
z = np.random.randn(100)

sc=plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap='viridis')
plt.clim(0, 100)
plt.colorbar(sc)
plt.xlabel("Actual")
plt.ylabel("Predicted")
sc.set_cmap('plasma')
sc.set_clim(-1, 1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code return for me an error `TypeError: You must first set_array for mappable` ...

The following is a simplest syntax that works for me:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random(100)
b = np.random.random(100)

scaled_z = (a + b)/a

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(a, b, c = scaled_z, cmap = 'plasma') ## you can directly change the colormap here
plt.colorbar()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```